# Query for a subset of blog posts in wordpress similar to query in squarespace example (that works)

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I am porting a website from SquareSpace to WordPress and ran across the scenario that I have not quite found an answer for and would respectfully appreciate any help.  In SquareSpace you can select multiple blog posts within the url link by specifying the blog tag (or blog category) in the url of the link.  Such as...

--> http://canyoncreek.net/new-blog?tag=landscape

I have not found the exact syntax for WordPress.  If I try something like this in WordPress I get the entire blog history...

--> linked as /news?tags=landscaping
--> rendered as https://canyoncreekaustin.net/news/?tags=landscaping

Notice extra / after ...news

Anyone know if this is doable in WordPress and the correct link syntax?

Comment: I checked your site, it seems you'r already adding categories to some blog posts, https://canyoncreekaustin.net/category/member-responsibilities/  That's the syntax you need to view all the blogs in that category. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: /category/ works perfectly but what about also searching for blog postings by their tags such as by /tags/?  I need that too.  A respectful thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Update...  Apparently /tag/ not /tags/ works.
--> https://canyoncreekaustin.net/tag/landscaping/

Not to be too greedy, but is there a way to select based on a logical condition condition.  Such as tag/landcaping OR tag/mowing... ?

Comment: Not really anything via just the url.  There's ton's of plugins out there that could probably add something like this as a filter though.

Comment: Thanks again @John for your excellent and speedy help.  -Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress you can add categories to you blog posts.  Which you can view all of the blogs in that category with the syntax of:

https://www.example.com/category/My_Custom_Category_Name/

To make a category, go to posts>categories and make some.  Then when you create a blog post assign it a category.